# MYSQL SUM with Inner Select returning max date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to come up with a single query which will take the following table (named `sales`):

```
user_id  |  order_total   |   order_date  |
    1    |      100       |  2012-01-01   |
    1    |      200       |  2013-06-04   |
    1    |      150       |  2012-01-08   |
    2    |      100       |  2015-02-01   |
    3    |      105       |  2014-10-27   |
```

And will return the following:

```
user_id  |  order_total   |   num_orders  |  last_order  |
    1    |      450       |     3         | 2013-06-04   |
    3    |      105       |     1         | 2014-10-27   |
    2    |      100       |     1         | 2015-02-01   |
```

So far I have come up with the following SQL to get the result:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT a.user_id,
SUM(order_total) AS order_total,
COUNT(*) AS num_orders,
b.order_date as last_order
FROM 
    `sales` AS a,
     (
        SELECT 
        order_date, 
        user_id
        FROM `sales` 
        ORDER BY order_date DESC
      ) AS b
WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY order_total DESC
```

The problem, however is that it returns:

```
user_id  |  order_total   |   num_orders  |  last_order  |
    1    |      1350      |     9         | 2013-06-04   |
    3    |      105       |     1         | 2014-10-27   |
    2    |      100       |     1         | 2015-02-01   |
```

Is there some way to prevent the sub-query from affecting the results of Sum and Count? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Try to specify by which user_id you group - a.user_id or b.user_id

Comment: Last order date for 1 is 2013-06-04 ? Or 2015-01-08?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri sorry, my mistake - I have corrected the example data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why are you using a subselect?

```
SELECT user_id, 
SUM(order_total) AS order_total, 
MAX(order_date) AS lastOrder, 
COUNT(*) AS num_orders 
FROM table 
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY order_total DESC
```

Comment: order by order_total DESC

Comment: Wow. I really made a meal out of that... thanks mate.